# How to cancel @jsonIgnore in specific method

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a domain javabean, some bean hvae a lot of information with password
and login Ip, I use the @jsonIgnore to filter that property which I dont
want the end user know.

But there has a problem,In other method 
I use the same javabean to send back
to front side,but now I need some property from this domain 
has anyway can cancel this @jsonIgnore in some specific method?

> @JsonIgnore
>
> private String address;
>
> private Integer drawnum;

but now I need address , I cant do this.....
I dont want to use the for loop to add in other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is the concept of `JsonView` : in some cases you want a set of attributes to be serialized, and in some other cases you want a (slightly) different set of attributes to be serialized.

Check this [excellent tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation), it explains evrything, even the use with Spring MVC.

Create classes to annotate the fields :

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Internal extends Public {
    }
}
```

Annotate the fields :

```java
public class Item {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public int drawnum;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String address;
}
```

In the controller, if you want only "public" properties to be serialized ;

```java
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
@RequestMapping("/items/{id}")
public Item publicItem(@PathVariable int id) {
```

Result : `{"id":2,"drawnum":5}`

In another controller, if you want all properties to be serialized ;

```java
@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
@RequestMapping("/items/{id}")
public Item internalItem(@PathVariable int id) {
```

Result : `{"id":2,"drawnum":5,"address":"My address"}`

Comment: You are complete answered my question,this way is better then I using Gson to make a json String to Object,thank you!!!!

Comment: @detail0805 Glad I could help! I discover this feature not long ago. Maybe you should you should accept this answer then, to mark the question as resolved.