# cancel @jsonIgnore in specific method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, attributes

Is there a way to change the JsonIgnore behavior depending on the method?

While researching, I found the below question. But I want to do something similar in .net
Is there a way to do this in .net?

[How to cancel @jsonIgnore in specific method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528464/how-to-cancel-jsonignore-in-specific-method)

Answer (score -1):

For the Newtonsoft.Json the easiest solution is just include a method ShouldSerializeFieldName, where the FieldName is the name of your field.
For example this will include the Description field only when it's length is less than 500:

```
public class QClass { 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDescription()
    {
        return Description.Length<500;
    }
}
```

....

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);

Comment: In this example, should serialize is set for all the routes/methods. My question is can we change this depending on the method/Controller/Route

Comment: @katie77 - then might you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63586748/edit) your question and state your precise requirements, ideally with a [mcve].  *Is there a way to change the JsonIgnore behavior depending on the method?* is quite vague, and this question seems to address that request.  Since you're asking for help from the [tag:c#] community the people who might be able to help you may not know details of Java serialization from the linked question not included in yours directly.